# fullCalendar v5 eventOverlap resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to check if events are overlaping at same resource.

Is there any way in eventOverlap function to get stillEvent and movingEvent resourceId where each event are positiones at overlapping moment?

I tried this but everything is undefined:

```
eventOverlap: function (stillEvent, movingEvent) {
        console.log(stillEvent.resource);
        console.log(movingEvent.resource);
        console.log(stillEvent.resourceId);
        console.log(movingEvent.resourceId);
}
```

If overlapping is in same resource then i need to return false, else i will return true.

Comment: No this doesn't seem to be possible. But why do you care which resource the overlap is occurring in? What do you want to do with that information?

Comment: If overlapping is in same resource then i need to return false, else i will return true.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want you can just set

```
eventOverlap: false
```

This will stop events in the same resource being allowed to overlap. Events which are in another resource are already considered as not (potentially) overlapping.

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoZeov

N.B. you cannot use eventOverlap to compare events in different resources, because the `eventOverlap` callback will not be triggered if an event is dragged onto a specific time period which overlaps with an event in another resource - as I said above, this is not considered by fullCalendar to be a potential overlap.